# Left outer join using LLBLGEN

Tags: c#, asp.net, llblgenpro

How i can perform left outer join in the following table

```
Product table
- productId (pk)
- productTitle
- pDescription

Product Status
- statusId (pk)
- productId (fk)
- comment
```

I need to select everything in Product table

```
DataAccessAdapter daa = clsMethods.GetNewAdapter();
IPrefetchPath2 pp = new PrefetchPath2(SDL.EntityType.ProductEntity);
pp.Add(ProductEntity.PrefetchPathProductStatus);


RelationPredicateBucket bucketbucket = new RelationPredicateBucket();
bucketbucket.Relations.Add(ProductEntity.Relations.ProductStatusEntityUsingProductId, JoinHint.Left)
```

Above code only return product which product id record in product status id. How i can perform left outer join which select everything from product table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you select starting with the ProductEntity? Fetch Product entities and prefetch the ProductStatusEntity?